Why Include and Reference().Load() don't work in Entity Framework Core
In my ASP.NET Core MVC application I try to select orders and I need to show customer:
var orders = await _context.Orders
                           .Where(o => o.DeletedAt.HasValue == false)
                           .Include(o => o.TheCustomer)
                           .OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderDateTime)
                           .ToListAsync();

<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor( modelItem => item.TheCustomer.FullName )
</td>

But customer is empty (not null).
This doesn't work either:
foreach (var order in orders)
{
    _context.Entry(order).Reference(o => o.TheCustomer).Load();
}

Here is Order class:
public class Order : SoftDeletableEntity
{
    public DateTime OrderDateTime { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public virtual Customer TheCustomer { get; set; } = new();
    public virtual OrderStatus? TheOrderStatus { get; set; } = new();

    [Required]
    public virtual DeliveryType TheDeliveryType { get; set; } = new();
    // ...
}

What's wrong? Please help
I checked using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; if it's not using System.Data.Entity.
I tried to use IQueryable.
Nothing helped.
I need to load customer to show name.

Not sure if it would help, but try removing the = new(); after each of the properties that have it.

You are right - I removed = new() and it works correct now. But now I get this warning "CS8618 - Non-nullable property TheCustomer must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring it as nullable." How can I fix it? If I add TheCustomer init in constructor customer is empty again.

I want TheCustomer field be not null.

I would instead recommend that you declare it as public virtual Customer? TheCustomer { get; set; };. Reason: it makes perfect sense to allow that an Order is loaded from the EF Context without always having to load the Customer, e.g. if all you want to do is update the OrderStatus property, and then save it back to the database. It would be unneeded overhead to always load the Customer. And what if the Customer has a required Address? You'd also have to load that address. This would explode if you have lots of non nullable properties.

+1 you should not = new() on singular navigation properties, only on collections. For a test, add a .AsNoTracking() to your Orders query.
What I suspect may be happening is that earlier code has loaded the order(s) without the eager loading, where those orders would have been initialized with the blank Customer reference due to the = new().  Later, when you try to load them with the Include EF is executing a query, but when it retrieves each Order from the tracking cache it is finding that they already have a Customer assigned so it does not overwrite with the values loaded from the database, it effectively thinks you have set them to new, blank customers.  Removing the = new() in this case should solve the issue. and is the most likely solution. Adding an .AsNoTracking() to the query would force EF to load the orders and customers from the database and would confirm the behaviour.
I don't recommend sending entities to the view engine to serve as models for MVC views, rather projecting to view models which can help avoid issues like this as neither the projections not the entities referenced are added to the tracking cache. If you do continue with binding to entities then I recommend using AsNoTracking() queries on read-only queries like this to have EF skip the steps of reading from, and adding the entities to the tracking cache.

Thanks for tip. But doesn't ToListAsync() do the same?

As AsNotracking()? The AsNoTracking() is included with the ToListAsync(). It just tells EF to ignore the tracking cache, both in terms not using entity references already tracked, and not adding newly read entities into the tracking cache. When you execute a Linq query EF will always run a query for the data, but if there are matching entities already in the tracking cache, EF will return those references. If those entities didn't have related references then it would have populated and tracked related entities from the SQL results.
